# How to repeat a loop?

Tags: r

this is my first loop:

```
e13 = rnorm(122)

y = 0*e13

y[1]=2
y[2]=5

for(k in 3:length(e13)) {
    y[k]=  0.6 * y[k-1] + e13[k]
}
```

Now I want to repeat it 10 times to find another 10 values for the same y[k], like, 10 different `y[1]`, 10 different `y[2]` and so on.

And then I need ot use these numbers for another functions.

I tried it but didn't work

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  for(k in 3:length(e13)) {
    y[k,i] = 0.6 * y[k-1,i] + e13[k,i]
  }
}
```

it says "wrong number of dimensions"

Now my code is like that:

```
e13 = rnorm(122)
y <- array(0, c(length(e13), 20))
y[1, ] <- 2
y[2, ] <- 5
i<-c(1:20)
y[1]=2
y[2]=5

for (i in 1:20) {
  for(k in 3:length(e13)) {
    y[k,i] = 0.6 * y[k-1,i] + e13[k,i]
  }
}
```

but the problem now is the dimension of e13 (a normal distribution), im going to try to set the correct dimension

Comment: Have a look at `?while` and `?repeat`.

Comment: Just wrap another for-loop around that code. You will need another dimension for y, however, and that requires pre-dimensioning it.

Comment: I edited my post with a new loop, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You get an error? (Which error?) Or your `y1` matrix is filled with values not as you expect? (What do you expect?). Also, how do you initialize `y1`?

Comment: As @IShouldBuyABoat indicated, you need to correctly set the dimensions of `y`. Instead of `y = 0*e13`, try `y <- array(0, c(length(e13), 20)); y[1, ] <- 2; y[2, ] <- 5`.

Comment: thanks guys, i will now try set the dimensions for e13

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that for `e13`. You can just move `e13 = rnorm(122)` such that it appears just before the inner loop starts, and then refer to `e13[k]`. Otherwise, if you give `e13` a second dimension (e.g. `e13 <- matrix(rnorm(122*20), nc=20)`), then you'll need to change `length(e13)` to `nrow(e13)` (or `length(e13[, i])`).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a good look at some introductory R texts (e.g., [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf), [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf), and others). The comments on your question were guiding you to solve this yourself. You're almost there, but here is how I would do what you're attempting.

```
e13 <- matrix(rnorm(122*20), ncol=20)
y <- array(0, dim(e13))
y[1, ] <- 2
y[2, ] <- 5

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
  for(k in 3:nrow(y)) {
    y[k, i] <- 0.6 * y[k-1, i] + e13[k, i]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already read a few introductory R texts in portuguese, but none of them were detailed enough for me. Thank you very much for your help and I will try to read these texts you sent me to become a better programmer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution although `cbind` will slow you down with larger datasets. If need more speed you don't need to specify 2 dimensions you can specify datamatrix as a vector of length `length(e13)*(how many times you want to repeat)` In this case `length(e13)*20`. Then in your second loop you would have y placed further along the length of datamatrix each repetition of the loop. Its sometimes simpler to do this and you turn it into a matrix at the end if you want using `matrix`.

```
datamatrix=NULL
for(n in 1:20) {
e13 = rnorm(122)

y = 0*e13

y[1]=2
y[2]=5

for(k in 3:length(e13)) {
    y[k]=  0.6 * y[k-1] + e13[k]
}
datamatrix=cbind(datamatrix,y)}
```

Comment: It works very well, as good as jbaums' one. I will now try to calculate a autoregressive model through matrix, and will try to use both answers to find the best way to do it. Thank you very much for your help, cheers.

Comment: Be aware, though, that in its current form, this will use the same `e13` vector each time through the `n` loop, leading to 20 identical columns in `datamatrix`.

Comment: Thanks @jbaums, i couldn't notice it. So this solution isn't usefull to calculate different ols through matrix, as they are all identical.

Comment: Moving `e13 = rnorm(122)` so it appears directly below `for(n in 1:20) {` will ensure a new random vector each time through `n`. You'd also need to change `y = 0*e13` to `y <- array(0, c(122, 20))` since `e13` won't exist yet in a clean workspace.

Comment: Woops, fixed it. Just moved the beginning of the loop up. I checked this time and it works. Sorry for bad answer. Thanks @ jbaums.

Comment: Specifying `y <- array(0, c(122, 20))` and using loops to fill in the 2 dimensions of the array is totally a better way of doing things. However if you're new to R `cbind` and `rbind` can do the same thing and may be simpler to understand. Using arrays can be frustrating because if you're off in either dimension it won't work where as there is not much you can mess up with `cbind`/`rbind`. That is why I also mentioned you could specify one long vector which to deposit all the data in and turn it into a matrix afterwards. Good luck with whatever you're using this for.

Comment: Sorry, my claim "You'd also need to change `y = 0*e13 to y <- array(0, c(122, 20))`" above was misguided... a simple `y <- numeric(122)` would suffice.